# Override magento 2 module file

Tags: magento2, template, overrides

I'm trying to override a file in my theme, but its not showing.
The file is located in

`vendor/mollie/magento2/view/frontend/web/template/payment/creditcard-with-components.html`.

location of my file is

`Vendor/Theme/Mollie_Magento2/web/template/payment/creditcard-with-components.html`.

Is this path wrong?

Comment: please check your theme name in app/design/frontend/

Comment: I think payment is html file, right?

Comment: yes, i updated the question @DhirenVasoya

Answer (score 0):

copy the file from :

```
vendor/mollie/magento2/view/frontend/web/template/payment/creditcard-with-components.html
```

to

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourTheme/Mollie_Magento2/web/template/payment/creditcard-with-components.html
```

And then run below commands :

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: that's what i did, doesn't show my changes.

Comment: Have you check, you are created proper path, like extension name is proper not any mistake there?